# is there a way return different types of a struct in the same function?

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I'm trying to use the nannou crate to randomly generate symbols, but I'm having trouble writing a function that randomly generates a symbol and stores it into the following struct

```
struct Sigil<T,U>{
    major:Drawing<'static,T>,
    minor:Vec<Drawing<'static,U>>
}
```

i tried to do the following

```
fn sigil_make<T,U>(app: &App)->Sigil<T,U>{
    let draw=app.draw();
    let mut sigil:Sigil<T,U>;
    match random::<u8>()%2 {
        0=>sigil.major=draw.ellipse(),
        1=>sigil.major=draw.polygon(),
        _=>println!("uh oh")
    }
    return sigil;
}
```

but this doesn't work as major is expecting type T while I'm trying to set it to a shape from nannou.

what would be the appropriate way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several problems all at once here.  I will list them along with the possible solutions.

- You allow the caller to specify the type `T`, but your function already knows the type itself.

  - Simply omit the `T` parameter.  (It may make sense for the caller to specify what `U` is since your function does not.)
- The two methods you are calling return different types, but Rust is statically typed and needs a *single* type.

  - Returning one type or the other at runtime requires either dynamic dispatch (usually seen as `Box<dyn _>` with a trait) or an "either" type, such as an enum with a variant for each possible returned type.
- These two methods also capture the lifetime of the `Draw` returned by `app.draw()`, but the `Draw` will be destroyed when the function returns.

  - Accept a `&Draw` instead of an `&App`, which will give you a longer-lived `Draw` to borrow from.
- The `_` arm of your `match` needs to evaluate as something of the same type as well.

  - Have this arm panic, or return an `Option`.  Since another value should not be possible, we can panic by using the built-in `unreachable!` macro.
  - Or, change the `1` arm to `_`.
- You partially-initialize the `Sigil`; the `minor` field is not initialized and so you cannot return it.

  - Initialize `minor` as well.
- `Sigil` specifies that the lifetimes of the `Drawing` values are `'static`, which is not guaranteed to be true.

  - Add a lifetime to `Sigil`.

Here's an example of how you could solve these issues:

```
struct Sigil<'a, T, U> {
    major: Drawing<'a, T>,
    minor: Vec<Drawing<'a, U>>,
}

// See also the "either" crate, which provides an enum like this.
enum Either<L, R> {
    Left(L),
    Right(R),
}

fn sigil_make<U>(draw: &Draw) -> Either<Sigil<'_, Ellipse, U>, Sigil<'_, PolygonInit, U>> {
    match random::<u8>() % 2 {
        0 => Either::Left(Sigil {
            major: draw.ellipse(),
            minor: vec![],
        }),
        _ => Either::Right(Sigil {
            major: draw.polygon(),
            minor: vec![],
        }),
    }
}
```